# jquery animation toggle not working

Tags: jquery

```
<div>
    <a href="#" class="click">Click1</a>
</div>
<div class='classshow'>Toggle Text1</div>
<div>
    <a href="#" class="click">Click2</a>
</div>
<div class='classshow'>Toggle Text1</div>
```

My Javasctipt Code:

```
$(".click").click(function () {
    $(".classshow").slideToggle("slow");
})
```

In this implementation the problem is all divs are getting toggles and i want only next to div gets toggled.
Please help

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are selecting all the elements with class of `.show`. Try the following:

```
$(".click").click(function() { 
   $(this).parent().next('.classshow').slideToggle("slow"); 
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8HRr/1/)

You can also selects the elements by using `href` attributes of anchor links.

```
<div>
    <a href="#first" class="click">Click1</a>
</div>
<div class='classshow' id='first'>Toggle Text1</div>
<div>
    <a href="#second" class="click">Click2</a>
</div>
<div class='classshow' id='second'>Toggle Text1</div>
```

```
$('.click').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // prevents the default action of the event.
  $(this.href).slideToggle();
})
```

Comment: i want only next "classshow" to be toggled.so where do u used the clasname

Comment: @MathsGal This selects the element with class of `classshow` by using `next` and `parent` methods. Is that current structure of your HTML?

Comment: i am asking solution for general case 
like what if structure is like
<div>
    <a href="#" class="click">Click1</a>
</div>
<div class='classNotToShow'>please dnt Toggle Text1</div>
<div class='classshow'>Toggle Text1</div>

Comment: @MathsGal There are different ways for doing so, try the updated code.

Comment: still u have not use based on class